# AJAX rest call error "unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a REST call with AJAX in this html page. First, the user enters a term in a search bar on the / page, and is redirected to /test, but the ajax call gets cut short. The API works fine when run on the console. I am just struggling to get the data over to the /test page so I can style it and display it for the user. I am using node.js btw.

The full error I am getting is:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                           hello.js:1
```

It is referring to the doctype declaration. 
I noticed something when I inspected the web page.

```
     <p> ID Passed: hello.js </p>
```

this is in the hello.js file...for some reason. The search term still gets rendered fine. It will say ID Passed: election

test.hbs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>

<h2>This is the test!!!</h2>
<p>ID Passed: {{ output }} </p>


<p2 id = "tweets">  



</p2>
```

hello.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET", //I have tried deleting both type and dataType and still fails
  dataType: "json", //I have also tried changing this to jsonp. No dice.
  url: './srch.js'

}) //Push the data from calling srch.js into the "tweets" id on test.hbs
.done(function(data) {
 document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML=data;
})
.fail(function() {
  alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
}) 
});
```

srch.js -> where the API is stored.

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./views/config');
var sentiment = require('sentiment');
var T = new Twit(config);
var params = {

    q: "election", //I know that the search term from the user isnt put in, I just want to see it print something on the page at all. 
    count: 1,
    type: 'recent'
};

T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);

function gotData(err, data, response) {
  console.log(err);

//Output only the text of the json data returned by the search, and perform sentiment analysis with the sentiment module. 

  for(var i = 0; i<data.statuses.length; i++) {
    document.write("Tweet " + (i + 1) + ":")
    document.write("***********************")
    document.write(data.statuses[i].text)
    document.write(sentiment(data.statuses[i].text).score) 
    document.write("***********************")
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the server?

Comment: Are you saying that the `<p>` element is somehow being injected into the hello.js file at runtime?

Comment: That, or the other way around. Something is causing it to expect something that is NOT html, which is why it throws an error as soon as it sees the first line... but other than that I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting back html instead of json.  I see that sometimes when url is invalid or when you are not authenticated so you get back html markup.

I would double check the return of the ajax call and display it in the console.

Comment: I tried logging it to the console by putting console.log(data) before and and after the doccument.getElementByID code. Nothing logs to the console.